# G-Sheet script to post a message on Guilded using its API

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a script to post a text message in a chat on Guilded, but so far I get a "POST is not allowed"
Message should be "inPrivate" so a mention of the targeted member is required.

[Google sheet test file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_XNvkG88NqQU_r5vvJFDMC37JvVEhRx7R5jl1FDdFn8/edit#gid=0)

my script:

```html
function message ()  {
  var url = "https://www.guilded.gg/api/v1/channels/";
  var channelid = "d2ba*****";
  var key = "Bearer gapi_*****";  //Q-P API temp-bot

  const message = {
    content : "It's alive!",
    embeds :[{
      author:"API",
      mentions:"Raven_test",
    }],
    isPrivate : true,
  }

  const params = { 
    method: "POST",
        headers: { Authorization: key },
        contentType: "application/json",
    payload: JSON.stringify(message),
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
  };
  
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(params));

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + channelid + "/messages/", params);
  var data = JSON.parse(response);
  Logger.log(data);

}
```

[Guilded's API](https://www.guilded.gg/docs/api/chat/ChatMessage)

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong (but I'm a newbie, so it makes sens)

Answer (score 1):

POST is still not working, with the same answer, however, if I use the PUT method, I can update a message if written by the same bot (I just need to add the messageid in the url after /messages/

```html
function postmessage ()  {
  var url = "https://www.guilded.gg/api/v1/channels/";
  var channelid = "d2bac803-****-****-****-a609ab9c58c4";
  var key = "Bearer gapi_******";  //Q-P API temp-bot
  var server = "wlVKV***"
  var messageid = "ae6f1693-****-****-****-c9984d4142de";
  var author = "****";

  const message = {
    "type": "default",
    "serverId":server,
    "channelId":channelid,
    "content" :  "test @Aaron Raven ",

    "mentions":{ 
      "users" : [{"id":author}]
    },

    "isPrivate":false,
    "isSilent":false
  };

  const params = { 
    method: "put",
        headers: { Authorization: key },
        contentType: "application/json",
    payload: JSON.stringify(message),
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
  };
  
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(params));

  // const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + channelid + "/messages/" + messageid, params);
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + channelid + "/messages/" params);
  var data = JSON.parse(response);
  Logger.log(response);
  Logger.log(data);
  Logger.log(params);
}
```

Another issue (aside POST method) is that "mentions" doesn't work; it appears as basic text, and not as a user tag/link

Kind regards,